# Directory Forbidden Neat Bourbon in Wordpress Editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, neat

We are creating a theme on Wordpress that makes use of Neat Bourbon. On the frontend everything works great. On the backend we are trying to display the content the way it will look so we also call Neat Bourbon. Our issue is Neat bourbon throws an error in nginx that the directory is forbidden. This is the only directory showing this error.

```
    [error] 11438#0: *290 directory index of "/var/www/wp-content/mu-
    plugins/folder/bower_components/neat/core/neat/" is forbidden, client: 
    XX.XX.XX.XXX, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /wp-content/mu-
    plugins/folder/bower_components/neat/core/neat/ HTTP/2.0", host: 
    "www.example.com", referrer: 
    "https://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?
    post=1318&action=edit"
```

Permissions are all the same:
[List of folders and their permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIk8f.png)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `GET` url is incorrect. The last `neat` is a sass file and not a directory.

Depending on how you are running your imports, the path should be one of the following.

```
/wp-content/mu-
plugins/folder/bower_components/neat/core/neat

/wp-content/mu-
plugins/folder/bower_components/neat/core/_neat.scss
```

See: https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/blob/master/package.json#L28